# Ruby 1.8 and 1.9 string differences

Tags: ruby

How can I get the first character of a string that works both in ruby 1.8 (bytes) and 1.9 (characters)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another solution

```
"string"[0].chr # => 's'
```

Answer (score 5):

This should do it...

```
s[0,1]
```

This returns the first byte in 1.8 and the first *character* in 1.9, but in each case the result is a String.

If you want the first UTF-8 character sequence in both, it's tricky. The regex engine is one place in 1.8 with UTF-8 awareness, so you could use:

```
s[/./u]
```

Comment: Thanks! But this assumes the first character is not multibyte?

Comment: This works, but it might be confusing to someone else looking at the same code *why* you're doing it. It is a good idea to either leave a comment in the code about this or use the more explicit `s[0].chr` if you're working on a team.

Comment: @Dennis, not exactly. It returns the first *byte* in 1.8 but the first *character* in 1.9.  I've updated the answer to discuss encoded characters.

Comment: I will go with intellidiot's answer since it's a bit more explicit as pointed out by coreyward also.